# Interpreting the amax parameter in scipy's line_search

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

In SciPy 1.0.0, according to [its documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.line_search.html), `scipy.optimize.line_search` has an optional parameter `amax` which determines the "Maximum step size".

As such, I would expect that the first return value, `alpha`, would always be less than the given `amax`, but this is not the case, as the following example illustrates:

```
from scipy.optimize import line_search

def f(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2

def df(x):
    return 2*x

x = np.array([4, 5])
line_search(f, df, x, -df(x), amax=0.001)
# Returns (0.5, 3, 1, 0.0, 41.0, array([ 0.,  0.]))
```

In this, the value of `alpha` is 0.5 but the value of `amax` is 0.001, which is less than 0.5.

Another interpretation might be that `amax` limits the distance between the output values `x_new` and `x0`, but this is also not the case.

Am I misinterpreting the documentation, or is this a bug in SciPy? And, if it is working as intended, what is the correct interpretation of `amax`, and is there some other way to limit the range of alphas in which to perform the line search?

Comment: Oh the line_search module. Touched it once and failed. It seems alpha's are increased (starting at 1) and therefore the first pick=1 is used for you. Do you need wolfe-conditions-based line-search. If not, i would try armijo-ls which will work from 1 towards 0. But of course it's something else. If you need to stick to this one, you might find some discussion in the issue-tracker on github and of course the pseudo-code in Nocedal's Numerical Optimization.

Comment: Armijo does (tried it) as expected (but still not answering your question).

Comment: Reading the code it *feels* like a bug. amax is never touched if the initial-guess works out. The differences to Nocedal are also puzzling: there amax is part of the init-phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sascha said, the current implementation of `line_search` (SciPy 1.0.0) does not handle `amax` correctly. Specifically, the function [`scalar_search_wolfe2`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py#L323) breaks out of the loop `for i in xrange(maxiter)` if a suitable alpha is found, while the check for `amax` appears later in the loop and is not reached.

Workarounds:

1. Use the older routine `line_search_wolfe1`, which is a wrapper for MINPACK's line search. It enforces not only `amax` but also `amin`, minimal step size.

```
from scipy.optimize.linesearch import line_search_wolfe1
line_search_wolfe1(f, df, x, -df(x), amax=0.001)
```

This returns `(None, 1, 0, 41.0, 41.0, array([ 8, 10]))` where None means that no suitable step was found. This is the correct answer: no step size of size at most 0.001 satisfies the Wolfe conditions.

2. Pass the requirement on the step as `extra_condition` argument to the `line_search` routine.

```
line_search(f, df, x, -df(x), extra_condition=lambda a, x, f, g: a <= 0.001)
```

This returns `(None, 13, 1, None, 41.0, None)` which again is correct: there is no suitable step size.

3. Perhaps you don't really mean to impose Wolfe's condition? Getting None as a (correct) answer isn't very helpful, after all. If so, use Armijo backtracking. The parameters are different: it does not ask for `df` function, but it does ask for the gradient and value at the initial point of the search. The parameter `alpha0` is the initial and maximal step size, the algorithm will only reduce it if necessary.

```
from scipy.optimize.linesearch import line_search_armijo
line_search_armijo(f, x, -df(x), df(x), f(x), alpha0=0.001)
```

returns `(0.001, 1, 40.836164000000004)`  meaning the step size is 0.001, there was 1 function evaluation, and the function value after the step is 40.8... which is of course smaller than 41 it was initially.

I don't see the documentation of `line_search_armijo` on the SciPy website, but we can read its [docstring on Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py#L605).

Comment: Tried it out a bit more, and indeed `line_search_armijo` behaves better, but it still has some surprises. For example, by using an (arguably broken) input direction with $\phi'(0) > 0$, it is possible for it return negative values of `alpha` (which you would not expect given that `amin=0` in `scalar_search_armijo`).

Comment: Yes, the source code says that `alpha>0` is assumed to be the descent direction, which means `derphi0` is assumed to be negative. This assumption underlies the inequalities involving alpha and amin.  I don't know why the line search doesn't simply error out in the case derphi0>0. But you can add this safeguard yourself: before calling `line_search_armijo(f, xk, pk, gfk, old_fval)`, make sure that `np.dot(gfk, pk)` is negative.

Comment: My guess is that when some  multivariable optimization routines that rely on line_search do not perform as expected, the line_search is tweaked so that it is more likely to keep on going, rather than raise an error and terminate the process.

Answer (score 0):

The bug will be fixed in SciPy 1.3.0 by [this pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9791) which changes the behavior to the expected one: A result step size of `None`.